# ES6 / Lodash, how to check if an object contains a specific value of given request?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6, lodash

With having an object like below, how would I know that a certain value, e.g: `template:d51a08fe-fb60-4da0-841b-03a732f19576`, existed in this object?

```
const obj= {
            "5871": "template:d51a08fe-fb60-4da0-841b-03a732f19576",
            "6993": "template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979",
            "5123": "template:280ac289-c726-4cb1-8a11-9ae1c987b399"
          };
```

I was trying to use lodash some but this will need the property name, but I cannot provide the property here such as `5871`

Comment: Check through all the values? What have you tried?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` to get a list of all values in your Object. This will return an array of all values. Then you simply use `includes` function on the array to see if that values exists in the array.

```js
const obj= {
            "5871": "template:d51a08fe-fb60-4da0-841b-03a732f19576",
            "6993": "template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979",
            "5123": "template:280ac289-c726-4cb1-8a11-9ae1c987b399"
          };
          
const valueExists = Object.values(obj).includes("template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979")

console.log(valueExists)
```

Comment: Yes, and if for some reason you need the property name as well, you can write something just slightly more complex against `Object.values` of your object.

Answer (score 1):

Lodash's `_.includes()` works with objects as well as arrays. In addition, you can use `_.findKey()` to, well, find the key:

```js
const obj = {
  "5871": "template:d51a08fe-fb60-4da0-841b-03a732f19576",
  "6993": "template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979",
  "5123": "template:280ac289-c726-4cb1-8a11-9ae1c987b399"
};

const exists = _.includes(obj, 'template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979')
const key = _.findKey(obj, v => v === 'template:d07479ff-1172-4464-996d-32d6c7358979')

console.log({ exists, key })
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/lodash.js/4.17.15/lodash.js"></script>
```